# Target only the first child element

Tags: html, css, nested, parent-child

I'm working on a WordPress plugin that has many nested classes. In the plugin the admin can add a class to one of the outer divs by doing this I can set some custom CSS rules.

The problem is I'm trying to just target the first child div class however whatever I try it targets all of the parent div classes.

Here it is on codepen
[Nesting divs](https://codepen.io/weberino/pen/OJdqVGP)

```
<div class="parent-item my-target">
  <style></style>  <div>darren div</div>
  <div class="child-item">
    Target
    <div class="parent-item">
        <div class="child-item">
          Hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent-item">
        <div class="child-item">
          good bye
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.child-item {
    border: 1px red solid;
}

.parent-item.my-target > .child-item:first-child {
    border: 5px blue solid;
}
```

:first-child doesn't work as there other elements before the target div
:first-of-type doesn't worl
:nth(1) is unreliable as it acts like first-child

Comment: first-of-type didn't work, I updated the codepen so you can see

Comment: In your given example, the element could be targeted simply via `.parent-item.my-target > .child-item`, leaving out the non-working `:first-child` - all the other `.child-item` elements in your example would not be affected, because they are not _children_ of `.parent-item.my-target`. Can't tell from just that one example though, if that is always what the situation will be like, or just lucky coincidence.

Comment: @CBroe Thank that's the solution!

Comment: The difference between using .parent > p {...} and .parent p {...} in CSS lies in the level of specificity and the elements they target.

.parent > p {...} selects only <p> elements that are immediate children of an element with the class .parent. It specifically targets <p> elements that are directly nested within the .parent element.

.parent p {...} selects all <p> elements that are descendants (children at any level of nesting) of an element with the class .parent. It targets all <p> elements inside the .parent element, regardless of how deep they are nested.